# Vue.js 2 Multiple Properties defined in one Single-File component

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on a Laravel 5.5 & Vue.js 2.x project, after several digging searchs and questions I came to components. But still I have a warning message when the page renders:

> **[Vue warn]:** Property or method "trimestral" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
>
> (found in < Root >)

I have the following Single-File component in a *Vue* file: FormExpenses.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" min="0" name="expenses" id="expenses" v-model="expenses">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <select class="form-control" name="expenses_range" id="expenses_range" v-model="expensesRange" :disabled="expenses < 1">
                <option value="" disabled="">Elija el rango de expensas</option>
                <option value="mensual">Mensual</option>
                <option value="trimestral">Trimestral</option>
                <option value="cuatrimestral">Cuatrimestral</option>
                <option value="semestral">Semestral</option>
                <option value="anual">Anual</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    module.exports = {
        props: {
            amount: {
                type: Number,
                default: 0
            },
            range: {
                type: String,
                default: '',
            }
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                expenses: this.amount,
                expensesRange: this.range,
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

I have registered the component "correctly" since some data seems to work. This is in the Vue instance file. Besides, I have defined the following element which seems it renders well in the form:

```
<expenses-form 
        :amount="@if(old('expenses')) {{ old('expenses') }}@elseif(isset($property) && $property->expenses) {{ $property->expenses }}@endif"
        :range="@if(old('expenses_range')) {{ old('expenses_range') }}@elseif(isset($property) && $property->expenses_range) {{ $property->expenses_range }}@endif"
        ></expenses-form>
```

This seems to be working because it shows the following while rendering:
[image: Form]

As seen, the first field is being rendered with their functions and data, but not the second one, despite according to [Vue.js documentatiob](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select) seems to be ok.

Any comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue expects `range` to be a string, but you're using v-bind (`:range` and Vue treats `trimestral` as variable, which is not defined), when passing a prop, instead of `:range="..."` use `range=""`.

More you can read in docs here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Literal-vs-Dynamic

Comment: but why `:amount` is taken as valid and `:range` doesn't? If both are passed properties...

Comment: When using v-bind you can pass more variable types, for example:
`:amount="9"` is treated as a Number,
`amount="9"` is treated as a string, and in your case, you defined amount type as a Number in component declaration.

Comment: Okay, I got it, so I should add quotes, for instance.

Comment: Ok, I've changed `:range` and `:value` for `range`and `amount`. Thank you, it worked.